# Custom form control property using form builder

Tags: angular

Is there a way to add a custom property called `filterMode` using the form builder in Angular? I'm creating a search form, but want to be able to tie a filter type to it like startsWith, contains, equal, etc. I'd like to have access to this value for each form control when I get the `FormGroup` controls object.

For example:

```
public queryForm: FormGroup;


constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.queryForm = this.fb.group({
      username: [value: '', filterMode:'contains'],
      email: [value: '', filterMode:'contains'],
    });
  }
```

Is there a way to extend FormGroup in Angular?

Comment: Sounds like you want a custom validator?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Not a custom validator, but a custom property I can see when I get the `FormGroup` -> `controls` object. I'd like to be able to access the username control and see that it has a filterMode of contains for example.

Comment: As far as I'm aware you would create a validator for this use case. Then you can provide your argument to the validator and update the validity based on what you provide.

Comment: Does it make sense to use the validator property if I'm not trying to validate the field, but just add a property I can access on the form group?

Comment: What are you going to use the property for? Never come across your use case before, a validator should in theory do what the name inclines, i.e. just validate. Not set properties.

Comment: That's why I'm not trying to create a validator. I just want a property I can set in my form builder called filterMode. Then I can pass my form somewhere to build a query off that property.

Comment: Hi @user2531854, I have the same idea in mind of making a filter from an angular form. Have you found a way to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a property on the control, after all it's just an object, and Javascript allows you to rewrite objects.

Simply with this.

```
constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    name: ['']
  });

}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.form.get('name')['filterMode'] = 'contains';
}
```

**[Here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lme3bp?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create component with value accessor.

Ref:https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

The idea is that you build component, implement value accessor & interface methods and then you can use that component as complex formgroup elements..something like:

```
constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.queryForm = this.fb.group({
      username: [value: ''],
      email: [value: '', filterMode:'contains'],
    });
  }
```

where your username would actually be:

```
export class SomeType {
   username:string,
   filterMode:string
}
```

So, basically, your `username` field of your form becomes of complex type `SomeType`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend the FormGroup class. you can create your custom component that implements `ControlValueAccessor` class from `@angular/forms`

if you do it that will allow you to use reactive-forms to handle the data model like a normal input

```
@Component({
    selector: 'custom-comp',
    templateUrl: './custom.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./custom.component.scss'],
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomComponent),
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class CustomComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange = (_: any[]) => {};
  constructor() {};
  /** Registers the onChange event. (used to implement the form control) */
    registerOnChange(fn): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    /** Register the onTouched event. (used to implement the form control) */
    registerOnTouched() { };
}
```

if you follow this approach you will be able to pass to this component the custom imputs and configs that you want